# how to save an outlook.com email as a file the same as MS outlook 2007

Tags: email, outlook.com

Is it possible to save an outlook.com file as a .html file or msg file the same as in MS Outlook 2007/2010?

Outlook.com has the advantage of being portable and easily hooks into your devices with an internet connection, but MS outlook 2007 has the advantage of being able to save emails onto the laptop. Is this functionality possible in Outlook.com?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Just open "Actions" menu for a selected message and choose "View message source". After that you can save the page as Text file right from your browser and rename the file's extension to .eml. That's all.

Comment: thanks for the solution. Is there away that I can save it in email format and keeping all the images and text format?

Comment: EML is an email format. It retains all the attachments and text format.

Comment: when I save the file I don't have the option to save as .eml so I manually type the extension but this doesn't save the pictures etc. Also when I click on view source it doesn't show the images either

Comment: It doesn't not show images because it displays MIME-structured message. This is strange that you can't see pictures in the saved EML. Did you try to open it using double-click?